# Yum does nothing(Unresponsive) when installing any package or updating

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm

I am having issues with using Yum on Redhat 7. Yum does nothing ("Unresponsive") when installing any package or updating even with sudo or root.

Here's what I did:

1. `yum install update`
2. `rpm --rebuilddb`
3. `yum clean all`

`yum install update` or `yum remove <any_package_name>` makes putty shell unresponsive.  `yum search <pkg_name>` works. `yum clean all` does not work either -- same symptoms. I did `rpm rebuilddb`, with no issues. This happened when I tried to remove webmin with `yum remove webmin`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my rpm unresponsive issue with:

```
cd /var/lib
mv rpm rpm.orig
mkdir rpm
restorecon -Rv rpm
rpm --rebuilddb
```

References:

1. https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/rebuilding-corrupted-rpm-database.html